# How can I open multi-panel using Expansion panel of angular material?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, panel, expansion

I want to use expansion panel in result i want to open multi-panels, like this example :
[open example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxYUo.jpg)

here is it my code:

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel hideToggle>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        This is the expansion title
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        This is a summary of the content
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>This is the primary content of the panel.</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
                       (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        Self aware panel
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        Currently I am {{panelOpenState ? 'open' : 'closed'}}
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>I'm visible because I am open</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Comment: Having a hard time understanding what exactly you want to achieve, could you clarify the problem, and also provide some code that didn't work ? The code sample is copypasta from https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/examples#expansion-overview

Comment: The following stackblitz provides a minimum example of nested mat expansion panels
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-v12-rc-view-engine-5xgchm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbadge-overview-example.html

Comment: @Simplicity's_Strength yes ! because I don't know how to edit the code in angular material, what I want is when I click in the arrow in the panel I want to open cards (multiples)  like it shows in the example (please check the link )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider the following [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-v12-rc-view-engine-5xgchm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbadge-overview-example.html)

Adding *hideToggle* *disabled* on the children expansion panels helped match the linked picture, two mat-accordions were used with the second having the *multi* attribute to allow having multiple panels opens

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel class="parentPanel" [expanded]="true">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header class="parentPanel_header">
      <mat-panel-title> Group </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-accordion multi>
      <mat-expansion-panel class="childPanel childPanelCount" [expanded]="true" hideToggle disabled>
        <p>Elements count {{elements.length}}</p>
      </mat-expansion-panel>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let i of elements">
        <mat-expansion-panel class="childPanel" [expanded]="true" hideToggle disabled>
          <p>Element</p>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
      </ng-container>
    </mat-accordion>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Some css was required to achieve a matching look, although this is not a css question

```
mat-expansion-panel.parentPanel {
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.parentPanel_header {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.childPanelCount{
  opacity: 50%;
}

.parentPanel mat-expansion-panel.childPanel {
  margin-top: 1em !important;
}

::ng-deep .childPanel div.mat-expansion-panel-body {
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: still have to turn it  dynamically.. Je suis encore débutante c'est pourquoi j'ai essayé de chercher des solutions sur google , stackoverflow pour apprendre .... en tt cas merci beaucoup !